# How to remove decimal point from the number using applescript

Tags: excel, macos, automation, applescript

i'm trying to access the excel cell using applescript and cell number keeps on changing and when ever i set the cell value to for example 20 it is taking as 20.0 which leads to an error.
Thanks in  advance.

Comment: What did you already try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a script ( from http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/sbrt/sbrt-02.html ) that fits your needs so you may want to try this:

```
my round_truncate(20.0, 0)

on round_truncate(this_number, decimal_places)
    if decimal_places is 0 then
        set this_number to this_number + 0.5
        return number_to_text(this_number div 1)
    end if

    set the rounding_value to "5"
    repeat decimal_places times
        set the rounding_value to "0" & the rounding_value
    end repeat
    set the rounding_value to ("." & the rounding_value) as number

    set this_number to this_number + rounding_value

    set the mod_value to "1"
    repeat decimal_places - 1 times
        set the mod_value to "0" & the mod_value
    end repeat
    set the mod_value to ("." & the mod_value) as number

    set second_part to (this_number mod 1) div the mod_value
    if the length of (the second_part as text) is less than the decimal_places then
        repeat decimal_places - (the length of (the second_part as text)) times
            set second_part to ("0" & second_part) as string
        end repeat
    end if

    set first_part to this_number div 1
    set first_part to number_to_text(first_part)
    set this_number to (first_part & "." & second_part)

    return this_number
end round_truncate

on number_to_text(this_number)
    set this_number to this_number as string
    if this_number contains "E+" then
        set x to the offset of "." in this_number
        set y to the offset of "+" in this_number
        set z to the offset of "E" in this_number
        set the decimal_adjust to characters (y - (length of this_number)) thru -1 of this_number as string as number
        if x is not 0 then
            set the first_part to characters 1 thru (x - 1) of this_number as string
        else
            set the first_part to ""
        end if
        set the second_part to characters (x + 1) thru (z - 1) of this_number as string
        set the converted_number to the first_part
        repeat with i from 1 to the decimal_adjust
            try
                set the converted_number to the converted_number & character i of the second_part
            on error
                set the converted_number to the converted_number & "0"
            end try
        end repeat
        return the converted_number
    else
        return this_number
    end if
end number_to_text
```

Answer (score 0):

My first advice is you should give a bit of examples to get closer to the answer you need. 
How do you get this "20.0" ? This looks like an automation by Excel, not Applescript.
So as long as you're working with Applescript, it should be OK to call

```
set myLineNumber to 20
get value of cell (A & myLineNumber)
```

Now if you're getting the "20" value from Excel, that's another thing cause Excel can come quite nasty with number values.
I don't have my Mac here, but trying things like

```
set myLineNumber to valueFromExcel mod 1 -- "mod" is for modulo
```

should do what you need.

You can also use "casting" which means turn for instance a text value like "20" to a number like 20.
For you case, this would be :

```
set myLineNumber to (valueFromExcel as integer) -- valueFromExcel being "20" or 20.0 for instance
```